# Счетчик времени чтения PDF файлов

Tags: python

решил создать счетчик времени чтения pdf файлов по дням недели, я нуб в Python и тем не менее))
Для визуализации графика времени/день буду использовать библиотеку *matplotlib*

**сам вопрос:** с помощью каких инструментов можно использовать запись статистики если она будет основываться на том, сколько времени запущен pdf на компе на протяжении дня?

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Дни = ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт',
       'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс']
Минуты = [10, 20, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150]

plt.bar(Дни, Минуты, color='blue')
plt.title('Статистика чтения')
plt.xlabel('Дни')
plt.ylabel('Минуты')
plt.show()
```

Comment: а как вы собираетесь выяснять, сколько времени был запущен pdf?

Comment: @strawdog Мне кажется в этом то у ТС и вопрос. Можно наверное следить за процессом соответствующим и писать в лог....